# Making video from BMP files in assembly

Tags: assembly, video-capture, x86-16, bmp

I work on a project on school on assembly 16 bit in DosBox(8086) and i have made a procedure which taking a screenshot(in BMP format) from and it works perfect. I want to make a video from these pictures.
i want to know which video format i should use(i want the simplest) and if some could explain me how to make the video file i would be perfect.

How i make the screenshot:

```
;--------------------------MakeScreenshot--------------------------
; Description:  Saving the screen posion in a file(in the log directory)
; Return:       Nothing.
;------------------------------------------------------------------
proc MakeScreenshot
    pusha
    mov bp, sp
    sub sp, 2
    push offset MkScrnshotLog1
    call AddToLog

    @MakeScreenshot@lineCounter         equ [word ptr bp - 2]
    ; creating the file
        push offset MkScrnshotLog3
        call AddToLog
        ; finding the last var in the arr
            push offset ScreenShotPath
            push 1000
            push 0
            call find

            cmp [index], -1 
            jne @MakeScreenshot@cont6
            call PError

    @MakeScreenshot@cont6:
        mov bl, [index]
        xor bh, bh
        add bx, offset ScreenShotPath
        sub bx, 6
        mov di, bx

    ; get the time
        ; CH = hour (0-23)
        ; CL = minutes (0-59)
        ; DH = seconds (0-59)
        mov ah, 2ch
        int 21h
        cmp dx, [SecAndMin]
        jnae @MakeScreenshot@cont
            inc [byte ptr di + 1]
            jmp @MakeScreenshot@SameSec

    @MakeScreenshot@cont:
        mov [SecAndMin], dx
        mov dl, dh
        xor dh, dh
        mov ax, dx
        cmp ax, 10
        jae @MakeScreenshot@Div4
            mov [byte ptr di], '0'
            inc di
            add al, '0'
            mov [byte ptr di], al
            sub di, 4
            jmp @MakeScreenshot@file

    @MakeScreenshot@Div4:
    ; Divide the number to digits in the stack
        xor si, si                  ; Si counts the number of digits
        mov bl, 10
    @MakeScreenshot@dig5:
        div bl                      ; Divide ax by 10
        mov cl, ah
        xor ch, ch
        push cx                     ; Save the digit in the stack
        xor ah, ah
        inc si
        cmp ax, 0
        jne @MakeScreenshot@dig5

        mov cx, si
        mov si, di
    @MakeScreenshot@Sec:
        pop ax
        xor ah, ah
        add al, '0'
        mov [si], al
        inc si
        loop @MakeScreenshot@Sec

        sub di, 3

    @MakeScreenshot@file:
        ; get the time
        ; CH = hour (0-23)
        ; CL = minutes (0-59)
        ; DH = seconds (0-59)
        mov ah, 2ch
        int 21h
        xor ch, ch
        mov ax, cx
        cmp ax, 10
        jae @MakeScreenshot@Div5
            inc di
            mov [byte ptr di], '0'
            inc di
            add al, '0'
            mov [byte ptr di], al
            inc di
            jmp @MakeScreenshot@creat

    @MakeScreenshot@Div5:
    ; Divide the number to digits in the stack
        xor si, si                  ; Si counts the number of digits
        mov bl, 10
    @MakeScreenshot@dig6:
        div bl                      ; Divide ax by 10
        mov cl, ah
        xor ch, ch
        push cx                     ; Save the digit in the stack
        xor ah, ah
        inc si
        cmp ax, 0
        jne @MakeScreenshot@dig6

        mov cx, si
        inc di
        mov si, di
    @MakeScreenshot@Min:
        pop ax
        xor ah, ah
        add al, '0'
        mov [byte ptr si], al
        inc si
        loop @MakeScreenshot@Min

@MakeScreenshot@SameSec:    
    cmp dx, [SecAndMin]
        jnae @MakeScreenshot@creat
            inc [byte ptr di + 1]
            jmp @MakeScreenshot@SameSec
@MakeScreenshot@creat:
    push offset ScreenShotPath
    push offset ScreenShotHandle
    call CreateFile

    ; write the header
        push offset MkScrnshotLog3
        call AddToLog

        mov ah, 40h
        mov bx, [ScreenShotHandle]  ; file handle
        mov cx, 54                  ; number of bytes to write
        mov dx, offset Fileheader   ; pointer to write buffer (the header is the same and we take a picture omly after the main page so i will not be empty)
        int 21h 
        jnc @MakeScreenshot@Cont20
            mov ah, 59h
            mov bx, 0
            int 21h
            push ax
            call PrintFileError
        @MakeScreenshot@Cont20:

    ; write the pallete
        push offset ScreenShotPalette
        call SavePalette
        push offset MkScrnshotLog4
        call AddToLog
        mov cx, 256
        mov bx, offset ScreenShotPalette
        xor di, di
        @MakeScreenshot@copyPal:
            ; Note: The palette of BMP files are BGR and not RGB so it has to be upsidedown.

            ; Copy last/first color (blue)
                mov al, [bx + 2]    ; Get the last color of the palette to the first color (blue).
                shl al, 2           ; The BMP palette is larger. ThereFore multyplayer by 4 in order ro corp it to the right size.
                mov [byte ptr ScreenShotPalette2 + di], al
                inc di

            ; Do the same on the second color (green)
                mov al, [bx + 1] 
                shl al, 2
                mov [byte ptr ScreenShotPalette2 + di], al
                inc di

            ; Do the same on the first/last color (red)
                mov al, [bx]
                shl al, 2
                mov [byte ptr ScreenShotPalette2 + di], al
                inc di

            ; enter an empty byte
                mov [byte ptr ScreenShotPalette2 + di], 0
                inc di

            add bx, 3               
            loop @MakeScreenshot@copyPal            ; It has to be 256 time becuase there are 256 colors im the palette.    

        mov ah, 40h
        mov bx, [ScreenShotHandle]          ; file handle
        mov cx, 256 * 4                     ; number of bytes to write
        mov dx, offset ScreenShotPalette2   ; pointer to write buffer 
        int 21h 
        jnc @MakeScreenshot@Cont2
            mov ah, 59h
            mov bx, 0
            int 21h
            push ax
            call PrintFileError

        @MakeScreenshot@Cont2:
        ; Copy the image
            push offset MkScrnshotLog5
            call AddToLog
            ; Declare the address of the video memory
                mov ax, 0A000h          ; The video memory is stored on A000:0000
                mov es, ax

            ; Copy
                mov cx, 200             ; 200 lines 
                mov @MakeScreenshot@lineCounter, 0      ; Reset the line counter
            @MakeScreenshot@copyImage:
                push cx                 ; Saves the cx for the big loop

                ; Copy one line
                    ; Declare where to copy from
                        mov di, offset ScreenshotLine

                    ; Declare where start to copy
                        mov si, @MakeScreenshot@lineCounter
                        mov ax, 320     ; We start to write a line on A000:lineNumber*320
                        mul si          ; Saves on dx:ax
                        mov si, ax      ; The max outcome fits into one word
                        ; Note: si now point where to write if the pic was not upside down

                        ; Make it 
                        mov ax, 63680   ; Ax = ((320 * 200) - 1) - 320 which is the start of the last line of the video memory 
                        sub ax, si      ; Ax now poit to the start of the oppesite line 
                        mov si, ax

                    mov cx, 320
                @MakeScreenshot@copyLine:
                    ; Copy from the stored line into the video memory
                        mov al, [es:si]
                        mov [ds:di], al ; Copy one byte from the stored line to the vide memory
                        inc si
                        inc di
                    loop @MakeScreenshot@copyLine

                ; copy the line to the file
                    mov ah, 40h
                    mov bx, [ScreenShotHandle]          ; file handle
                    mov cx, 320                         ; number of bytes to write
                    mov dx, offset ScreenshotLine       ; pointer to write buffer 
                    int 21h 
                    jnc @AddToLog@Cont3
                        mov ah, 59h
                        mov bx, 0
                        int 21h
                        push ax
                        call PrintFileError
                    @AddToLog@Cont3:
                inc @MakeScreenshot@lineCounter
                pop cx                  ; Return the value to cx
                loop @MakeScreenshot@copyImage

    ; close the file
        push [ScreenShotHandle]
        call closeFile

    add sp, 2                       ; Delete local var

    popa
    ret
endp MakeScreenshot
```

Comment: Simplest? Uncompressed rgb ... will be large and you will have to tell the player the format so it won't be "click to play".

Comment: Hm... I think FFmpeg might support some trivial uncompressed video formats.  If you use one of those and put it into an mkv container or similar, it might just play back in a normal video player.

Comment: @Jester I know it will be large but the videos will be short with low frame rate and resolution of 320*200 so it won't be that bad.

Comment: @flikhamud45 Some users recommend [y4m](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/YUV4MPEG2), an uncompressed video stream with good support.  Might be tricky to get the colour space right though.  Let me research some more.

Comment: You might also get away with generating animated gifs instead.  That file format was engineered to be particularly easy to generate from standard VGA graphics and does not require any compression.

Comment: If you use uncompressed AVI, the bitmap format is pretty much the same as BMP, so that might be the easiest solution yet. If you use uncompressed AVI, the bitmap format is pretty much the same as BMP, so that might be the easiest solution yet.

Comment: @fuz thanks, i will try researching about uncompressed AVI. if you find anything important just let me know, thanks for helping.